# Error on terminal start

Tags: rvm, ruby-1.9.3

```
-bash: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: /Users/janekambani/.bash_profile: line 1: conditional binary operator expected
-bash: /Users/janekambani/.bash_profile: line 1: syntax error near `"$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"'
-bash: /Users/janekambani/.bash_profile: line 1: `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" '
```

I tried this:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/rvmrc /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh /usr/local/rvm /usr/local/bin/rvm $HOME/.rvm $HOME/.rvmrc
```

but i still kept getting the same error.
im using OS X 10.8

Comment: maybe post your .bash_profile or at least the beginning of it

Comment: i typed this: source ~/.bash_profile
but i still got the same error:

Comment: Yes, you would.  source just tries to load it again.  Hard to say what is wrong with the file without seeing what is in it.

Comment: If you're trying to get the contents of the file so you can post it here then do `cat ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: ok so i did that, and this is what i got:

Comment: [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" 
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" 
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" 
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" 
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" 
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

Comment: export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Developer-Preview:$PATH

export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Developer-Preview/command:$PATH

export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Developer-Preview/jsbuilder:$PATH

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

Answer (score 17):

Take a look at the source of /etc/profile.

On 10.8 of Mac OS, installing RVM while using sudo, adds a line to /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh.  Even if you remove RVM using `rvm implode`, that one liner stays in there and will cause that error to show on start up of any terminal.

Comment: Comment out these two lines the /etc/profile file on Mountain Lion

> # source /etc/profile.d/sm.sh
> # source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh

Comment: So that's where that pesky line was coming from! Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Use your favorite text editor (`nano`,`vim`, etc) to open `/etc/profile` and comment out these two lines:

```
source /etc/profile.d/sm.sh
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
```

Then save the file.

Comment: This sounds like an advertisement for Sublime. Any text editor, such as pico, nano, vim, or emacs will work. It doesn't take Sublime to do the task, as much as I like that editor.

Comment: This worked for me, but OSX wouldn't allow me modify the file with TextEdit, etc. I had to use `sudo vi /etc/profile` (I'm sure `sudo nano...` would work too if you go for that sort of thing)

Comment: I could not edit with TextEdit on my Mac either even after changing the security settings in Get Info.  I used TextMate to modify the file.

Comment: @theTinMan Edited That

Comment: @Holyprogrammer: Please don't use comments to notify us of edits. The system puts edit attempts into an approval queue and notifies us.

Answer (score 7):

To fix any issues with sourcing RVM use:

```
rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles #OR:
rvm get head --auto-dotfiles
```

It will remove existing sourcing lines and add new ones that are meant to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to a botched installation of RVM (at least the part that tried to install the shell loader was botched).  Did you recently try to [install RVM](https://rvm.io/)?

Something kept trying to insert the RVM load code and it has made a mess.

Here is my suggestion:

1. Make a backup copy of your `.bash_profile`.
2. Open it in a text editor and remove everything but:

   ```
   export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Developer-Preview:$PATH 
   export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Developer-Preview/command:$PATH
   export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Developer-Preview/jsbuilder:$PATH
   ```

Add this line below that:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Save it and open another terminal and see if the error goes away.

Comment: i tried it out:$ export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Developer-Preview:$PATH export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Developer-Preview/command:$PATH export PATH=/Applications/SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-Developer-Preview/jsbuilder:$PATH [[-s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
-bash: export: `[[-s': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `/Users/janekambani/.rvm/scripts/rvm': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `]]': not a valid identifier

Comment: i recently installed osx 10.8, had a problem ever since then.

Comment: I usually prefer fresh installs but YMMV.