# No such file or directory when opening terminal

Tags: ruby, rvm

I had a hard time installing the Rails environment, but everything I need is installed. I  have one issue left, now every time I open the terminal I get this:

```
- bash: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: No such file or directory
```

I'm using OSX 10.7. Any idea?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839748/error-on-terminal-start