# OS X 10.8.3 Terminal Error After RVM install

Tags: terminal, rvm

I am an amateur front-end web developer with a decent handle on html5, css, and jquery.
 Recently, I have been venturing into unknown territory with Ruby on Rails. After watching my fair share of tutorials, I figured I would give it a try.

Thus, I  installed Ruby & Rails via http://railsinstaller.org; however, after install, it was suggested that I download the LATEST versions through RVM. Thus, I uninstalled railsinstaller and attempted to install Ruby on Rails through RVM, but I kept receiving a permission denied error whenever I would try to run the initial terminal `\curl` command.

I searched for troubleshooting tips online and found a few that seemed helpful. Unfortunately, now not only is RVM not installed, my terminal director is all screwed up.

Whenever I launch terminal, it says

```
-bash: /etc/profile.d/sm.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: export: `/Users/joebruno/.rvm/scripts/rvm': not a valid identifier
```

and my terminal commands no longer work. How do I reset my terminal directory?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839748/error-on-terminal-start

Comment: How do use Sublime Text 2 to open /etc/profile to comment out the problematic lines? What command do I run?

Comment: Ok. Figured that part out. I I commented out the two problematic lines. But I still get the "export" error above. Any ideas how to fix this?