# -bash: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: rvm

I recently update my default ruby version, by using

```
$ rvm --default use x.x.x
```

After doing so, and restarting my terminal I got the following error

```
-bash: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: No such file or directory
```

What exactly is the rvm.sh file and how did go missing by changing the default?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839748/error-on-terminal-start

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was better to deinstall all Ruby/gems and rvm completely.
Although rvm left lots of garbage in a system including sourcing rvm.sh from different places.

After full rvm deinstall one should check following files and remove all references to rvm:

In ~/ (user home folder):

```
.bash_profile
.bashrc
.zprofile
.zshrc
```

In /etc folder:

```
.bash.bashrc
profile
zprofile
```

Still have no idea why rvm puts so much garbage into system